# How to fix pdf.js rendering error of my website in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, pdf

I am trying to make a pdf viewer in html template using pdf.js in Django framework.

I had used a code that I got from a Youtube channel Traversy Media on how to create a custom PDF Viewer With JavaScript. It is working in Mozilla Firefox but not in Google chrome.

These are the errors that I got from the console log:

```
 1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xhr' of undefined
at NetworkManager_getXhr [as getRequestXhr] (network.js:239)
at PDFNetworkStreamFullRequestReader_onHeadersReceived [as _onHeadersReceived] (network.js:353)
at NetworkManager_onStateChange [as onStateChange] (network.js:168)
at NetworkManager_request [as request] (network.js:137)
at NetworkManager_requestFull [as requestFull] (network.js:88)
at new PDFNetworkStreamFullRequestReader (network.js:328)
at PDFNetworkStream_getFullReader [as getFullReader] (network.js:292)
at WorkerTransport.<anonymous> (api.js:1753)
at _callee$ (message_handler.js:25)
at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)

2. network.js:137 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/New%20folder/pdf_viewer-master/andro.pdf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.NetworkManager_request @ network.js:137

3. network.js:419 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reject' of undefined
at PDFNetworkStreamFullRequestReader_onError [as _onError] (network.js:419)
at XMLHttpRequest.NetworkManager_request.xhr.onerror (network.js:126)
at NetworkManager_request [as request] (network.js:137)
at NetworkManager_requestFull [as requestFull] (network.js:88)
at new PDFNetworkStreamFullRequestReader (network.js:328)
at PDFNetworkStream_getFullReader [as getFullReader] (network.js:292)
at WorkerTransport.<anonymous> (api.js:1753)
at _callee$ (message_handler.js:25)
at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:288)

4. main.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numPages' of null
at HTMLButtonElement.showNextPage (main.js:62)
```

here's the link of the pdf.js full code in github...

https://github.com/bradtraversy/pdf_viewer/blob/master/js/main.js

I hope someone can help me to have this working in Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Try to post your pdf on the internet and access to it rather than to local file. It looks like there is a CORS issue.

Comment: I am just a student and very new to this. I am not familiar with CORS but had some research earlier. What do you mean by posting my pdf on the internet?

Comment: Upload it to any filesharing  with direct access to files (it may be github as well) and load them in your app. 

Error you have `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file: ....has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension`

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for all the clarifications.